# For Kotlin/JS project conversion I'm getting type mismatch: inferred type is XXX but ZIndex? was expected

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, kotlin-js

When trying to add a z-index to a Kotlin JS project the documentation doesn't provide an example:

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/org.w3c.dom.css/-c-s-s-style-declaration/z-index.html

```
css {
        zIndex = 12
    }
```

I need to know what's the right way to assign a z-index in Kotlin-JS. So far I tried to use `12.px` but I get errors such as:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Length but ZIndex? was expected
```

Answer (score 2):

After unsuccessfully trying to read the documentation by looking at the code I found the following function:

```
inline fun integer(
    value: Int,
): IntegerType =
    value.unsafeCast<IntegerType>()
```

in that way I can apply the `z-index` value I want:

```
input {
        type = InputType.text
        css {
            zIndex = integer(12)
        }
    }
```